# Import from a cdn.js module

Tags: javascript, cdn

I'm a beginner in javascript and so i don't have a lot of knowledges about good practisies and possibilities.

**The problem**

I want to use [this pdf library](https://pdf-lib.js.org) to edit some pdf files. But i can't manage to import the library without nodejs or something else.

**What i tried**

In my html file i have the scripts imports statements :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./assets/js/Client.js"></script>
```

The second line is the import of my script in which i want to use the pdf library.

In my script "Client.js" i have the following code lines:

```
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib'

mypdf = window.PDFDocument.load(file)
```

`File` is an imported file thank to an event.dataTransfer.

I'm currently using the live server extension of visual studio code as environment.

When i load my page on the browser at

> http://127.0.0.1:5500/Client.html

I get the error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "pdf-lib". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I understand the error but it's not "a relative reference" in my case and i don't know what to do with this...

I made some researches of how to get it works with cdn js but every solutions i found aren't working

Comment: Remove ```import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib' ``` line if you are not using npm module. For browser use, umd build and window.PDFLib is enough Check: https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib#umd-module

Comment: I am having the same problem. Were you able to figure it out? If so, mind sharing what you did. Trying to edit a pdf as well using the same library

Comment: I solved my issue using nodejs and by installing the library with npm